# Exercise 7.7.29 Resnick's Book.

Tags: probability-theory, law-of-large-numbers

I tried to solve it and I couldn't. If anyone can help me how to resolve or a hint where to start.

$\mathbf{7.7.29}$

Suppose $\{X_n, n > 1\}$ is iid with common distribution described as follows.
Define

$$
p_k =\displaystyle{\frac{1}{2^kk(k+1)}}, \hspace{.5cm} k \geq 1,
$$

and $p_0 = 1 - \displaystyle{\sum_{i = 1}^\infty} p_k$. Suppose

$$
P[X_n = 2^k-1] = p_k, \hspace{.5cm} k \geq 1
$$

and $P[X_n = -1] = p_0$· Observe that

$$
\displaystyle{\sum_{i = 1}^\infty} 2^kp_k = \displaystyle{\sum_{i = 1}^\infty} \bigg( \frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+1}    \bigg) = 1,
$$

and that $E(X_n) = 0$. For $S_n = \displaystyle{\sum_{i = 1}^n}, n > 1$, prove

$$
\displaystyle{\frac{S_n}{n/\log_2 n}} \overset{P}\longrightarrow -1
$$

Comment: What did you try so far?  Where did you get stuck?

Comment: I thought I'd start by defining convergence in Probability. $\displaystyle{\lim_{n \to \infty}}P(\vert X_n - X \vert > \epsilon) = 0$ dizemos que $X_n \overset{P}{\longrightarrow} X$ and use the Markov inequality but I dont´t know how to link with the $p_k$

Comment: Almost two months later, do you still need a hint or an answer to  this question?